# Assigning variables from a string problem

Tags: c, function, variables

I'm trying to assign 'hp' , 'd', 's', 'status' respectively from an input file which has the content '600 144 100 Rain' . I have sucessfully assigned 3 of the numbers to hp,d,s ,but the 'Rain' string remains undone
since it appeared blank screen everytime I try adding it in. Here is my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_file(int *hp, int *d, int *s, char t[]) {
    FILE *infile, *outfile;

    infile = fopen("input1.inp", "r");
    // input1.inp's content is "600 144 100 Rain"
    
    fscanf(infile, "%d %d %d %s", &hp, &d, &s, t); 
    
    printf("hp = %d\n",hp ) ;
    printf("d = %d\n",d ) ;
    printf("s = %d\n",s ) ;
    printf("status = %s", t) ;


    fclose(infile); 
    return 0;
}
```

If I odd the 'Rain' string out then my code run perfectly.
Can someone show me how to do it properly, what mistake did I make ?

Please notice that declaring variables in the parameter area is compulsory for me , I need it to pass the variables to the main part . Thank you !

Comment: Think a little more about what data-type the `%d` format expects, and what data-type `hp` is and what `&hp` then is.

Comment: This guy ^^ is right. Also, how did you declared t[] in main? does it has enough space to store the string? (ie does it has at least 6 char's allocated)

Comment: @GalBirka An allocation of at least 5 characters is satisfying. (4-character `Rain` + 1 terminating null-character)

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by passind data having wrong type to `fscanf()` and `printf()`. Be careful because `hp`, `d` and `s` are pointers.

The part

```
    fscanf(infile, "%d %d %d %s", &hp, &d, &s, t); 
    
    printf("hp = %d\n",hp ) ;
    printf("d = %d\n",d ) ;
    printf("s = %d\n",s ) ;
```

should be

```
    fscanf(infile, "%d %d %d %s", hp, d, s, t); 
    
    printf("hp = %d\n",*hp ) ;
    printf("d = %d\n",*d ) ;
    printf("s = %d\n",*s ) ;
```

Also the results of `fopen()` and `fscanf()` should be checked.

Comment: ah thanks I modified like you suggested and I'll add fopen and fscanf check , but how do you fix the assign 'Rain' to t[] problem ..? I'm still stuck on that , thank you .

Comment: @amantohere [This fixed program will work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zzYmJFDeAhp6hisH).